# NodeJS - Writing to File Sometimes Finishes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an electron app and in it, I'm writing to a file.

```
if( fs.existsSync(envFilepath) ) {
    envFile = fs.createWriteStream(envFilepath)

    var envs = document.getElementById("envs").value.split(",")
    envs.forEach( function(env) {
        if( env && env.localeCompare(" ") !== 0 ) {
            env = env.trim()
            envFile.write(env + '\n')
        } 
    })

    envFile.end()

    envFile.on('finish', function syncConfigs() {
        //perform additional tasks
    })
}
```

Sometimes, the array `envs` has elements and it will write. For those moments, `end()` is called and `finish` event is caught and I roll along smoothly. However, sometimes, `envs` could be empty and I don't write to the file. NodeJS seems to hang because I didn't call a `write()` and the `finish` event never gets called.

Why is this happening? Is there a workaround for this situation?

Comment: How is that you have a mix of node.js `fs` code and browser `DOM` functions like `document.getElementById()` in the same body of code?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm using Electron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `fs.createWriteStream()` you should listen for the `'close'` event not the `'finish'` event.

```
envFile.on('close', () => {
  // handle done writing
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work-around your issue by just not opening the file if you don't have anything to write to it.  And, if you just collect all your data to write, it's both more efficient to write it all at once and simpler to know in advance if you actually have anything to write so you can avoid even opening the file if there's nothing to write:

```
if( fs.existsSync(envFilepath) ) {

    function additionalTasks() {
        // perform additional tasks after data is written
    }

    // get data to be written
    let envs = document.getElementById("envs").value.split(",");
    let data = envs.map(function(env) {
        if( env && env.localeCompare(" ") !== 0 ) {
            return env.trim() + '\n';
        } else {
            return "";
        }

    }).join("");
    // if there is data to be written, write it
    if (data.length) {
        fs.writeFile(envFilePath, data, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                // deal with errors here
            } else {
                additionalTasks();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // there was no file to write so just go right to the additional tasks
        // but do this asynchronously so it is consistently done asynchronously
        process.nextTick(additionalTasks);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I forgot about querying the length of the array I returned. But this answer is definitely another solution!

Comment: @akcorp2003 - I think this is technically a more efficient solution because it collects all the data to write, tests once if there is anything to write and then writes it all at once.  It even avoids opening the file if there is nothing to write.  Your current approach opens and closes the file even if there is nothing to write and then writes out small pieces at a time if there is something to write.